# Program not working when picking random Coin and Card

Tags: python

Hi I am very new to coding and I have no clue why this is not working! We have to make a program where the user either picks a coin and a random coin toss outcome is displayed or they pick card and a random card suit and number is displayed. It keeps coming up saying 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "\\fs1epa\intake2010data$\cresm011.311\My Documents\Year 11\Computer Science\Python Practise question\Card_or_coin.py", line 30, in <module>
    program()
  File "\\fs1epa\intake2010data$\cresm011.311\My Documents\Year 11\Computer Science\Python Practise question\Card_or_coin.py", line 9, in program
    if r == (1):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment
```

Here is my code:

```
def program():
Choice = input("Pick either 'Card' or 'Coin' ")
if Choice == "Coin":
    import random
    r = random.randint(1,2)
if r == (1):
    print ("Heads!")
elif r == (2):
        print ("Tails!")

if Choice == ("Card"):
    import random
card_number = random.randint(1,13)
if card_number == 1:
    print("Ace")
elif card_number == 11:
    print("Jack")
elif card_number == 12:
    print("Queen")
elif card_number == 13:
    print("King")
else:
    print(card_number)

flag = True
while flag:
    program()
    flag = input('Would you like to run the program again? [yes/no]') == 'yes'

print ("The program will now terminate.")
```

As you can see im not the best at coding but any help? Also when I type 'Coin' it works but still calculates a random card number and when I type 'Card' it gives me the above error. Also I haven't added a code for a random suit yet.

I added a persons code and now it works!!! however when I type 'Coin' It gets a random card number as well.

```
def program():
    Choice = input("Pick either 'Card' or 'Coin' ")
    if Choice == "Coin":
        import random
        r = random.randint(1,2)
        if r == (1):
            print ("Heads!")
        elif r == (2):
            print ("Tails!")

    if Choice == "Card":
        import random
    card_number = random.randint(1,13)

    if card_number == 1:
        print("Ace")
    elif card_number == 11:
        print("Jack")
    elif card_number == 12:
        print("Queen")
    elif card_number == 13:
        print("King")
    else:
        print(card_number)

flag = True
while flag:
    program()
    flag = input('Would you like to run the program again? [yes/no]') == 'yes'

print ("The program will now terminate.")
```

Comment: Is your indentation written in your code the same as it is displayed in this post? If so, it is not correct, everything within a function definition (under `def`) needs to be tabbed over. On that note, indentation in Python is **very important**.

Comment: Yes everything is indented it went strange when I pasted it in.

Comment: The loop works its just when I type 'Card' when I get the error

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong, you are trying to access variable `r` which is not a global variable, but local to the first `if` block

Comment: Your indentation is wrong - `if r == (1):` should be *inside* the block starting `if Choice == "Coin":` (also: see [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: Your indentation is **still wrong**, now you have *the exact same problem again*. Indentation is important in Python, you need to figure it out. Also, you should `import` once, at the top of the script.

Comment: When I change my indentation it gives me an error. The program runs but I need to get a way to ,when I type 'Card', it skips the coin process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment of `r` is out of the scope of your initial if on Choice.

Essentially, you were calling `if r == 1` before `r` was declared. This caused your error.

Remember that Python uses whitespace, so you'll need to indent accordingly.

I've rewritten (added 2 indents) your code for you and tested.

```
def program():
    Choice = input("Pick either 'Card' or 'Coin' ")
    if Choice == "Coin":
        import random
        r = random.randint(1,2)
        if r == (1):
            print ("Heads!")
        elif r == (2):
            print ("Tails!")

if Choice == ("Card"):
    import random
    card_number = random.randint(1,13)
    if card_number == 1:
        print("Ace")
    elif card_number == 11:
        print("Jack")
    elif card_number == 12:
        print("Queen")
    elif card_number == 13:
        print("King")
    else:
        print(card_number)

flag = True
while flag:
    program()
    flag = input('Would you like to run the program again? [yes/no]') == 'yes'

print ("The program will now terminate.")
```

Comment: I have edited my post with another problem now... I will change the name

Comment: Your pasted code does not match mine. Look at the two, you're missing an indent again. I've put the code here (http://pastebin.com/ZFLUv8pD) for you to grab from.

If you start an `if` statement, you should be able to "drop a ruler" down it, and see the entire scope. Anything that is equal to, or to the left of this "ruler" is out of scope.

Comment: Oh im sorry for wasting time. I will look more closely next time, thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: No worries - gives me something to do.

Try using the thought of "dropping a line" down any scopes. You can then see what is in and out of scope. Notepad++ is a good IDE for this.

Comment: Thank you, my school does not want to get Notepad++ for some reason but you have helped lots.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to intend the if and elif under the

```
if Choice == "Coin":
```

line.

Like this, you check for r==(1) every run trough the program. You want to skip it if you write "Card".

What is the compilator complaining about is, he does NOT do the assingnment

```
r = random.randint(1,2)
```

line, because he skips the if if the Choice is NOT the "Coin"

then he tries to compare it to (1), what he can't, because he did not do the assignment.

Comment: Like I said I am new to coding and im not sure what you mean.

Comment: As people above me answered, the indentation in Python is very important. If something is indented so it's more on the right side than the if, it will do it if the if statement is resolving. However, if it's indented the same as the if, it does not belong "in" the if, and it will be resolved either the if statement is true or not. Your r=random.randint is not "in" the if, but it should be.

Answer (score 1):

As the error msg says:

> local variable 'r' referenced before assignment

I think that would be enough information for you to see the error.

Usually you'll get `NameError: name 'r' is not defined` if you run `if r == 1:`, but Python thinks `r` is a local variable if it sees assignment like `r = random.randint(1,2)` thus throw `UnboundLocalError`.

Your program has many errors, for the one you asked, correction is:

```
import random

if Choice == "Coin":  
    r = random.randint(1,2)
    if r == 1:
        print("Heads!")
    elif r == 2:
        print("Tails!")
```

Comment: I have used that in my code and when I type 'Card' It still doesn't work and gives me the same error

Comment: @Mitchnana It's impossible I think. Would you post your updated code?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help. I have got it working and I am very grateful! I hope I wont have to ask for help again and I will be able to help others with the same problem as me.

**Finished Program:**

```
def program():
    Choice = input("Pick either 'Card' or 'Coin' ")
    if Choice == "Coin":
        import random

        r = random.randint(1,2)
        if r == (1):
            print ("Heads!")
        elif r == (2):
            print ("Tails!")

    if Choice == "Card":
        import random
        card_number = random.randint(1,13)

        if card_number == 1:
            print("Ace")
        elif card_number == 11:
            print("Jack")
        elif card_number == 12:
            print("Queen")
        elif card_number == 13:
            print("King")
        else:
            print(card_number)

flag = True

while flag:
    program()
    flag = input('Would you like to run the program again? [yes/no] ') == 'yes' , 'Yes'

print ("The program will now terminate.")
```

Oops it was my indentation, I didn't realise when I was looking at it, Thanks everyone for the help.